# why "bash: cqlsh: command not found"

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am running Cassandra 2.2.14 on a virtual machine (CentOS). The issue is that I cannot run the command "cqlsh" to create tables and keyspaces.

when I was tipping at the terminal:

```
cqlsh localhost ks-schema-local.cql
```

bash shell :

```
bash: cqlsh: command not found
```

cf) java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First install Cassandra to your computer, then go to bin directory and type:

`./cqlsh`

It should work if Cassandra is running in the default port (9160).

Comment: The version of cqlsh that ships with Cassandra 2.2 does not connect on port 9160.

Answer (score 0):

is cassandra installation directory is in your classpath?, add cassandra bin directory to your classpath, or execute from bin location.

Comment: I'm not sure where my cassandra installation directory is but when I see sudo service cassandra status -> It's active running but cqlsh is not working